# Extract titles from powerpoint textboxes (not placeholders)?

Tags: vba, pdfbox, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I've a PDF file which was originally created from a PPT (which I don't have access to). I need to extract the titles/headings from each page of the PDF into a single document (format irrelevant; Excel, Notepad, Word, anything will do). The file is big therefore, cant be done manually and I will have to do it for similar files again.

I concluded that converting the PDF back into PPT format would help and I am trying to write a Subroutine in PowerPoint VBA. Please take a look at the code below and suggest what I can change to accomplish this? Alternate ideas also welcome.

Heads up: Once converted back into PPT, the titles in each slide are no longer in the 'Title' placeholder, in PowerPoint. They are just normal textboxes. I'm new to VBA, I've compiled the code by Googling.

Output: This prints out a notepad file with list of slide numbers. For each slide it prints that respective slide number as many times as there are textboxes in the slide. For example: Slide 1 has 3 textboxes therefore, the notepad reads:

"Slide: 1

Slide: 1

Slide: 1

Slide: 2

Slide: 2

Slide: 2

Slide: 2

Slide: 2

Slide: 2

Slide: 2"

Problem: It is not printing the text from the textboxes. Actually, I need the text from only the top textbox (which is first or topmost placed on the slide).

Code:

```
Sub GatherTitles()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim strTitles As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim PathSep As String
Dim Shp As Shape

If ActivePresentation.Path = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please save the presentation then try again"
    Exit Sub
End If

#If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
#Else
    PathSep = "\"
#End If

On Error Resume Next  ' in case there's no title placeholder on the slide
For Each oSlide In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides

    For Each Shp In oSlide.Shapes
      Select Case Shp.Type
        Case MsoShapeType.msoTextBox

    strTitles = strTitles _
        & "Slide: " _
        & CStr(oSlide.SlideIndex) & vbCrLf _
        & oSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        Case Else
          Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, "This is not a text box"
      End Select

    Next Shp
Next oSlide
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

intFileNum = FreeFile

' PC-Centricity Alert!
' This assumes that the file has a .PPT extension and strips it off to make the text file name.
strFilename = ActivePresentation.Path _
    & PathSep _
    & Mid$(ActivePresentation.Name, 1, Len(ActivePresentation.Name) - 4) _
    & "_Titles.TXT"

Open strFilename For Output As intFileNum
Print #intFileNum, strTitles

NormalExit:
Close intFileNum
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume NormalExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really aren't *doing* anything with the variable Shp beyond checking if it is a text box. I don't have enough to go on to test the solution, but before the line

```
& vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

try inserting the line

```
& ": " & Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Its now printing content from each textbox. Now, I just have to test each textbox if it is the title one or not and print only if it is a title textbox. Do you know a possible way to do this? Do ask me if you need any further information. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, how do *you* tell which text you want? Once you figure that out, be kind enough to tell your code. It might be as simple as always being the second textbox on the slide. If it is more complicated than something like that, read the text into a string variable and see if it satisfies your criteria for being a title textbox.

Comment: I checked the output btw, the titles are not always first, second or last. They vary. Further, text content varies in length so I need to actually test the textbox position. Titles are the textboxes topmost on the slide (highest value on Y axis). Can u tell me the appropriate statements or code for this?

Comment: As you iterate through the shapes, look at their tops (Shp.Top). That property measures where the top of the shape is relative to the top of the slide. The smaller Shp.Top is, the closer to the top of the slide. Keep a shape variable which points to the textbox which is closest to the top (updating it when you find a shape closer to the top). After you iterate through all shapes on a slide, grab the text from the shape you have just found.

Comment: Figured it out finally. Thanks a lot guys !! :D

Answer (score 0):

If the text boxes aren't placeholders, the only way to do it is to check the position of each shape on the slide. Set X and Y accordingly below.

```
Sub GetTitles()
Dim oSld as Slide
Dim oShp as Shape
Dim myText as String
For Each oSld in ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oShp in oSld.Shapes
If oShp.Left=X and oShp.Top=Y Then
my Text=oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
Debug.Print myText
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, your idea to test the textboxes is exactly what I need. However when I run your code, I get this run time error:

"Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
The specified value is out of range."

When I click on 'Debug' it highlights line 8 (my Text=oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) in yellow.

The debug window doesn't update either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Btw, I have tried removing the space in that line:
myText=oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

Same result.

Comment: The shape may not have a text frame or text.  If oShp.HasTextFrame Then | If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then | do stuff with the shape

Comment: Hey, Got the solution. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated!! :D

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted of behalf of the OP.)*

The problem has been solved. Final code for reference just in case someone else starts VBA PowerPoint:

```
Sub GatherTitles()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim strTitles As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim PathSep As String
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Mn As Double

If ActivePresentation.Path = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please save the presentation then try again"
    Exit Sub
End If

#If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
#Else
    PathSep = "\"
#End If

On Error Resume Next  ' in case there's no title placeholder on the slide
For Each oSlide In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides
Count = 0

    For Each Shp In oSlide.Shapes
      Select Case Shp.Type
        Case MsoShapeType.msoTextBox
Count = Count + 1
        Case Else
          Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, "This is not a text box"
      End Select
    Next Shp
Count = Count - 1
Dim distmat() As Double
ReDim distmat(0 To Count)
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
    For Each Shp In oSlide.Shapes
      Select Case Shp.Type
        Case MsoShapeType.msoTextBox
distmat(i) = Shp.Top
i = i + 1
        Case Else
          Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, "This is not a text box"
      End Select
    Next Shp
Mn = distmat(0)
i = i - 1
For j = 1 To i
If distmat(j) < Mn Then
Mn = distmat(j)
End If
Next j

'Next oSlide

'For Each oSlide In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides
    For Each Shp In oSlide.Shapes
      Select Case Shp.Type
        Case MsoShapeType.msoTextBox
 If Shp.Top = Mn Then
    strTitles = strTitles _
        & "Slide: " _
        & CStr(oSlide.SlideIndex) & vbCrLf _
        & oSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
        & Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Else
Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, "This is not the topmost textbox"
End If

        Case Else
          Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, "This is not a text box"
      End Select

    Next Shp
Next oSlide
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

intFileNum = FreeFile

' PC-Centricity Alert!
' This assumes that the file has a .PPT extension and strips it off to make the text file name.
strFilename = ActivePresentation.Path _
    & PathSep _
    & Mid$(ActivePresentation.Name, 1, Len(ActivePresentation.Name) - 4) _
    & "_Titles.TXT"

Open strFilename For Output As intFileNum
Print #intFileNum, strTitles

NormalExit:
Close intFileNum
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume NormalExit

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. I don't think you need to store all of the tops in an array. The comparisons that you need to make in order to determine the top-most box can be made in the original loop rather than in a subsequent loop -- in which case there is no need to ever store more than 1 top value.

Comment: I was attempting to use the code. It works sometimes. However, other times it doesn't print anything to the file. I haven't looked closely at the code but if anyone did encounter this error, let me know.